# How to make SHAP's DeepExplainer work with deepctr library

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, shap

I am using DeepCTR (version `0.7.5`) keras library to predict ctr (using DeepFM)
https://deepctr-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deepctr.models.deepfm.html.
Here is a small example of the code to fit the model:

```
#Imports, then feature preperation...

model = DeepFM(linear_feature_columns, dnn_feature_columns, task='binary')
model.compile(optimizer, loss)
train_model_input = [train_df[name] for name in feature_names]
model.fit(x=train_model_input, y=train_df[TARGET].values, validation_split=0.3)
```

But when I try the following:

```
e = shap.DeepExplainer(model, test_df.head(50))
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (50, 17) for Tensor 'x:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'
```

I looked all over google and tried playing alot with the inputs shape and the SHAP API but nothing worked for me.
**Additional info**:
The model inputs format (17 values) is:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'x:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'x1:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=int32>...
```

And outputs is:

```
<tf.Tensor 'prediction_layer/Reshape:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>
```